# Acesso Proibido ao copiar e colar novo home.php

Tags: codeigniter, apache, xampp

Tenho um projeto e ele é todo em inglês na página principal sendo a "home.php", eu consigo acessar ela normalmente em local usando "localhost/CoLWithGit", porém, eu preciso fazer uma versão desta página em português, assim eu fiz uma cópia do home.php e renomeei para home_br.php, porém, ao acessar esse arquivo com "localhost/CoLWithGit/application/views/home_br.php" ele dá o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei bastante na internet mas não consegui solução.
Uso Windows 10 e estou usando o xampp com o CodeIgniter.
Tentei mudar no httpd-xampp.conf mas esse arquivo meu vai até a linha 109 sendo que nos tutoriais que vi, tinha que mexer na linha 122 e nele também não tem o lugar onde adiciona a instrução. O que posso fazer para acessar esse arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! Em CodeIgniter você nunca pode acessar *view* ou *model* diretamente pela URL. O acesso à estes arquivos se dá via *controller*. Perceba que na sua URL você nomeadamente acessa o diretório application, o diretório das views e a própria *view*, nesta ordem:

`localhost/CoLWithGit/application/views/home_br.php`

Para ver esta *view*, prepare uma função, dentro de algum *controller* de sua preferência, que a chame e a exiba, por exemplo num *controller* que se chamasse "alpha":

```
public function minha_view_portugues() {  
    $this->load->view('home_br.php');
}
```

Você acessaria a view por meio de:

`localhost/CoLWithGit/alpha/minha_view_portugues`

No entanto, recomendo, ao invés de empregar *views* diferentes em função do idioma, empregar a solução nobre para internacionalização e localização oferecida pelo CodeIgniter que é a biblioteca Language Class:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html

Ainda que a biblioteca requeira um estudo inicial, seu uso poupa dias de retrabalho, abstrai o problema de idioma no site, e expõe o conteúdo para que seja possível ser traduzido por tradutores externos ao projeto num segundo momento. Boa sorte!

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, funcionou! Eu estou com problemas na página exatamente igual a outra que tá certa, mas agora algumas imagens sumiram mesmo com o mesmo diretório.... Mas obrigado!